# Unable to compile Actor class in Unreal Engine 4 - error MSB3073 exited with code 6

Tags: unreal-engine4

I'm new to UE4, and I'm currently following a tutorial on converting blueprint to c++ on learn.unrealengine.com. I created a scene component class and successfully reparented the corresponding blueprint to that class.

When I tried to make the Actor component, UE said that it was unable to compile the class, therefore it won't show in the Content Browser unless I rebuild the entire module. I did that, but the files didn't show up in the Content Browser. I opened VS, and built the solution, which was unsuccessful, unlike the previous build. This is the error message:

`C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2019\Community\MSBuild\Microsoft\VC\v160\Microsoft.MakeFile.Targets(46,5): error MSB3073: The command ""C:\Program Files\Epic Games\UE_4.26\Engine\Build\BatchFiles\Build.bat" BlueprintsToCppEditor Win64 Development -Project="C:\Users\Admin\Documents\Unreal Projects\BP to C++ - Course Project Files\02 Starter Kit Overview\BlueprintsToCpp\BlueprintsToCpp.uproject" -WaitMutex -FromMsBuild" exited with code 6.`

How can I fix this? My VS version is 16.9.4

Comment: have you tried repairing your visual studio installation through the visual studio installer? or regenerating the project files?

Answer (score 0):

Could you please share the cpp file of the actor class which your trying to complie. To my knowledge this error is due to some #include statement missing.